# R: data frame column with empty char strings turns to NA on read

Tags: r, dataframe

Idea is to create and update catalog by `rbind`-ing data frames. This includes sequentially reading and writing files. Problem appears when for some data frames certain character string columns don't contain any values (blank chr strings ""). Somehow R treats those columns as NULL value and apparently removes them. Binding these data frames produces NAs, instead of desired "".

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = "", stringsAsFactors = F)
write.csv(df, "df.csv", row.names = F)
df <- read.csv("df.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
df <- rbind(df, data.frame(a = 1:5, b = "a", stringsAsFactors = F))
write.csv(df, "df.csv", row.names = F)
df <- read.csv("df.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)

> df
   a    b
1  1 <NA>
2  2 <NA>
3  3 <NA>
4  4 <NA>
5  5 <NA>
6  1    a
7  2    a
8  3    a
9  4    a
10 5    a
```

Obviously, desired output contains "" instead of NA.

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve it, but I think that "" in a csv is seen as a blank field. From the help from `read.csv`: Blank fields are also considered to be missing values in logical, integer, numeric and complex fields. As such, reading `""` as `NA` seems expected behaviour to me.

Comment: You could add quote="" to read.csv which helps, only it changes your column names from a to X.a

Comment: it does not help since it changes "" to "\"\""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use the parameter `colClasses` when importing your data with `read.csv` because, here, R doesn't see a character variable for `b` as there are only "" values and so R interprets "" as `NA`:

```
read.csv("df.csv", stringsAsFactors = F, colClasses=c("numeric", "character"))
#    a b
#  1 1  
#  2 2  
#  3 3  
#  4 4  
#  5 5
```

Comment: This does solve the problem, thanks. And on the side note - not if those frames come with weekly frequency.